# Adding Integration Services requires reboot?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 EE (10.0.1600) running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 EE and I need to add Integration Services to run Maintenance Plans. Because this is a production system I need to know if adding SSIS will require a reboot of the server or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Add Integration Services to an exixting SQL 2008 EE instance does not require reboot.

Answer (score 2):

If you stop all the SQL Services during the install and the service pack install, then a reboot shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As said above this is a production system, stopping services and reboot is same thing here.

Comment: True, but stopping the services for the install will require a much shorter outage than rebooting the system.